# Netbeans 6.7.1 Bug,Feature or Correct Php Syntax

Tags: php, netbeans, object

I develop My Php Apps with **Netbeans**.
If i acces a object like this **$this->db->**
and hit the space key it just shows me "No suggestions".
But if i acces the same object like this **$this->db-**
and hit the space key it shows me correct suggestions for complettiong the code.
Is this a bug a feature or is this the correct php syntax like **$this->db-q** which i dont think its the correct syntax for accesing objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it's a bug. It is correct if $this->db and q are numbers, where q is a constant. But $this->db is a db object, isn't it?

If you use this

```
/**
 * @var DbClassName
 */
 public $db;
```

maybe Netbeans will find you what you want.

**EDIT:**
This one works, but this is a nightly build. There could be other bugs:

http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/

Answer (score 0):

If you type "$this->db->" and it doesn't show code completion options then try Ctrl-Space rather than just space. I'm using 6.7.1 and I haven't noticed the problem you are describing.

Comment: hy sorry it should be the ctrl key plus the space key